# Unable to create new Django Project

Tags: python, django

I have python, pip and django installed. I have created a virtual environment, installed Django inside it and trying to create a new project via the following command:

```
(venv)c:\Users\username\Desktop\venv>.\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject test_project
```

Instead of creating the folder test_project along with its file, my PyCharm ide automatically starts and opens the django.admin.py file.

When I check inside my venv folder, only the default folders exists and test_project is not created. Can I know how to fix this please.

Comment: It should be `django-admin.py` not `django.admin.py`.

Comment: it seems you assign `.py` extension to `PyCharm` - it should be assigned to `python`.  But you still can do `python .\Scripts\django.admin.py ...`

Comment: @xyres Did u meant .exe?

Comment: @JasSy No, I mean the name of the script is `django-admin.py` not `django.admin.py`. [See this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project).

Comment: @xyres That's my bad. Typo error here. I am typing as django-admin.py on my command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
django-admin startproject test_project
```

it should be django-admin, not django-admin.py, If I remember correctly, it is new since 1.7

Comment: Well, I have version 1.8 and I can confirm `django-admin.py` works just as fine.

Comment: It works without the .py extension. Mine is 1.9.1. Thanks.

Comment: @xyres https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/ I am not sure if django-admin.py is still there, but it seems to be

Comment: django-admin.py is still there, but being deprecated, IIRC.

Comment: I stand corrected; there was a discussion about deprecation, but nothing set it stone: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21845 Still, not using the `.py` is best practice going forward.